# web.config settings not respected in .net core 3.1 Azure multi-instance scaled app service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm trying to add/remove certain http headers from responses coming back from a 'pure' web api application (i.e. no MVC) published to Azure.

I added the following web.config to the project in VS2019:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff"/>
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN"/>
        <remove name="X-Powered-By"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

This works fine in my dev environment with IISExpress. It also works fine when the app is published to Azure for app services that are not configured for multi-instance scaling. However, when the app service is configured for **multi-instance scaling** (three instances in my case) then responses from the app contain 'X-Powered-By' and no 'X-Content-Type-Options' or 'X-Frame-Options'.

Publishing creates the following web.config in Out folder on my dev machine:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
        <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
        <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath=".\<apname>.exe" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile="\\?\%home%\LogFiles\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also verified that the above web.config is present in the root of the app service in Azure.

Is there anything else that needs to be done in app service configuration in Azure for this to work with multi-instance scaling?

Comment: Which platform you use in webapp?

Comment: I'm using Windows platform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After testing, you do not need to make any changes. In the code or web.config, your solution is currently possible, provided that it is deployed in a windows-based webapp. If it is deployed under linux, then the web.config file is not effective. The `web.config` file is only applicable to `iis`. Under `linux`, the configuration file that needs to be used should be `.htaccess`.

**Put web.config under the wwwroot path, which is the root directory of the project.**

[image]

Based on windows azure webapp, the post-deployment effect should be consistent with the local iis effect. After testing, after I deploy, you can see the screenshots, and the effect in your web.config has been achieved.

**Note:**

*Some headers cannot be deleted, but they can be overwritten. They need to be coded in the program. You are not involved in this question yet.*

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="X-Content-Type-Options" value="nosniff" />
    <add name="X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN" />
    <-- replace server vaule -->
    <add name="Server" value="N/A" />
    <remove name="X-Powered-By" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

[image]

**Test Steps:**

## Method 1 with web.config

1. Create a sample project like below.

   [image]
2. Deploy to azure, please see my files on scm site.

   [image]

## Method 2 without web.config (workaround, also works in linux)

Add below code in `Startup.cs`, it also works for me .

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Content-Type-Options", "nosniff");
    context.Response.Headers.Add("X-Frame-Options", "SAMEORIGIN");
    context.Response.Headers.Remove("X-Powered-By");
    await next.Invoke();
});
```

[image]

Comment: app.Use() in startup.cs works for me now. This is great because I was trying to avoid bringing more packages (e.g. NWebsec) to the project. However, I could not make it to work with web.config. There might be an issue with multi-instance scaling of Azure app service. When deployed to app service without scaling web.config works fine. I'll update my original post accordingly.